# fullpage.js first load section css animate and get current index

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

the title maybe not clear, sorry about that :(
here is the code and [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vhr8zftm/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'red'],
        anchors:['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
        scrollBar: true,
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
            $(this).find('.animated').each(function() { // i want to know in here, $(this) mean active section? am i wrong?
              $(this).addClass('in'); // add in class to active section > animated item
            });
            $('.section:not(".active")').find('.animated').each(function() {
              $(this).removeClass('in');
            }); // each time scroll to section, remove in class at non-active section AFTER load (scroll)
        },
        afterRender: function(){

        },
    });
});
```

1. please view the link to see the code, thanks, problem is when reload page at first section, in class not add to it, but work at second section, how can fix this? (at link maybe not see the problem because each time run the code it go back to first section, i test the code not in http://jsfiddle.net/, reload page should scroll to same section as url#secondSlide something like that...sorry i dont know how to say this)
2. and at the afterRender part, i want to get the current section (index) each time reload the page, then run a function afterRender, i dont know how to get current index but i try add below code inside afterRender function, in fact i dont really know afterRender function meaning...

please view the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vhr8zftm/1/)

if i reload at second section, second section run afterLoad function and first section section run afterRender function when it not have class .active, seem my code fail, maybe dont need randerAfter function? :(

i want when each time reload page, current(have .active class) section add .in class to .animated with delay 1500 once, only once, then every scroll use afterLoad function (add .in class with no delay), i am thinking the idea when reload page, run function add_in_class_with_delay to current, unbind this function after run once, bind add_in_class_without_delay function, i dont know how to do this.

any good method? thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, that you are just adding a CSS class, I would recommend you to play with the class that fullPage.js adds to the `body` element to determine in which section / slide are you in.

Do this:

```
body.fp-viewing-firstSlide .animated{
    transform: rotate(0deg) ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) ;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.animated {
    transform: rotate(122deg) ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(122deg) ;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
}
```

Comment: the answer work, may i ask one more question? fullpage.js when i reload at fp-viewing-1, body class will show at fp-viewing-0, how can i use this css method on this? thanks so much :)

Comment: @aboutjquery not sure what are you asking for. Try to explain it differently.

Comment: hello :) sorry, my code mistaken, now problem solved, css method work very good, thanks so much :)